# Oracle begin...end block gives no errors but does not work

Tags: mybatis

When i use mybatis with Oracle begin-end block.
I want to execute two update once.
this is my code:

```
@Update("begin" +
        " update pt_jg set usernum = usernum+1 where jgbh in (#{bm});" +
        " update pt_bm set usernum = usernum+1 where bmbh in (#{bm});" +
        "end;")
public int incUsernum(@Param("bm") String bm);
```

There are no warnings or errors but it does not work.
The database has no changes.
The oracle version is 12c.

Comment: That means the transaction is rolled back, probably. Add transaction-related information to the question. If you could share a small demo project like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues) that replicates the problem, I may be able to give you the direct answer.

Comment: ok, here it is.[mydemo](https://github.com/lonelyhiker/so-61837995).

Comment: You didn't include DDL, so I have to ask. What is the data type of `jgbh` and `bmbh`? If it's `CHAR`, that may be the reason (and even a single update may not work). If you can change the data type, changing them to `VARCHAR2` would be the easiest solution. If you can't, you may have to 1) cast the bind parameter to char (e.g. `in (cast(#{bm} as char(x)))` or 2) use string function like `rtrim()` or `rpad()` in the WHERE clause because `CHAR` is a fixed-length data type.

Comment: no man, i try to change the code like this.
`@Update("begin" +
            " update pt_jg set usernum = 1 where jgbh = '15';" +
            " update pt_bm set usernum = 1 where bmbh = '15';" +
            "end;")
    public int incUsernum();`
it doesnt work. i guess the data type is no matter. and i use debug to check, the affected rows were -1.

Comment: Please add `CREATE TABLE` statement to the question. Using your demo, I have verified that the rows are correctly updated when the table definition is `create table pt_bm (usernum int, bmbh varchar(20))`. I also verified that the problem you described (no error / rows not updated) reproduces when using `create table pt_bm (usernum int, bmbh char(20));`

Comment: god damn.i know whats the problem. i should use `${bm}`. sorry weste your time, im so sorry man.

Comment: No worries. Glad to know the issue was resolved. :)